# Kafka consumer behavior for non existent offset

Tags: apache-kafka

I am a newbie to Kafka and there are certain things which are not clear to me.

1. Kafka broker goes down will the producer go down.
2. Kafka broker goes down will the consumer go down.
3. If we start at an offset which doesn't exist would it be struck infinitely.

Answer (score 2):

1. The producer will not go down, it will select another (live) broker to produce to. If there are no other live brokers, you will get an error in the producer's response (anyway it will not crash).
2. The consumer will not go down, the consumer(s) will rebalance the remaining (live) partitions. If you have replication for the partitions on this broker, their leader will change.
3. It won't stuck. The behavior in that case depends on what you set in the `auto.offset.reset` of the consumer config (https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs).
   If you set it to `earliest`, it will reset the offset to the earliest available one in the partitions.
   If you set it to `latest`, it will reset the offset to the latest available one in the partition.
   If you set it to `none`, it will throw an exception to the consumer.

As for 1 & 2 - if you wish that the producer/consumer will stop in that case, you can implement it with some coding.